# android - okhttp3 - ssl connection to server

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate, okhttp

I am sending GET and POST requests to my server using the OkHttpClient (okhttp3).

How can I secure the connection with SSL and identify myself with a self signed certificate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Self signed [SSL](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html) certs check [here](https://gist.github.com/chalup/8706740). The link contains code samples to add self signed SLL to Android.

Self Cert using okhttp3 , Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42288868/okhttp3-accept-all-certificates-and-use-a-certificatepinner)

Hope this may help you.